# Enviar un Boolean de un adapter a su fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, método

tengo un problema, tal vez me puedan ayudar ,
en el evento onclick de un recycler quiero enviar un boolean a su fragment para que actualice un metodo, pero no se como hacerlo.

antes ya lo había realizado pero no con un adapter desde un fragment, este es el codigo del adapter que me funcionó antes.
Adapter

```
  holder.btMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
  ((ActividadPrincipal) view.getContext()).updateItemCount(true);
 }
```

y lo recibía en la actividad principal de esta manera:

```
     public void updateItemCount(boolean ifIncrement) {
    if (Common.cartRepository.countCartItems()==0) {

      //  Linearlayoutvacio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     //Linearlayoutlleno.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

intente hacerlo de la misma manera enviando un bollean a su fragment cambiando solo "Actividad Principal" por "Mi fragmento" pero no funciona.

```
((Selection2) view.getContext()).updateItemCount(true);  ----AQUI OCACIONO EL ERROR NO ME DEJA COLOCAR "Seleccion 2"EL CUAL ES MI FRAGMENT
```

agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Usa un `callback`

Crea una `interface` con tu método.

```
interface TuCallback{
    void updateItemCount(boolean b);
}
```

Implementa tu `fragment`.

```
class TuFragment extends Fragment implements TuCallback{

    @Override
    public void updateItemCount(boolean b){
        ...
    }
}
```

Pásalo a tu `adapter`, y en el `onClick` usas el `callback`.

```
class TuAdapter extends Adapter{
    private TuCallback callback;

    public TuAdapter(TuCallback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    ...

    holder.btMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 callback.updateItemCount(true);
            }
}
```

Comment: Amig@ muchas gracias tu ayuda,hice todo  pero no logro pasarlo a mi adapter,

Comment: por favor tu ayuda

Comment: Tu adapter hereda de RecyclerView.Adapter<T>?